# Angle of impedance derivation

Tags: capacitor, impedance

I've been working to understand this proof, but some parts are too hard mathematically. [image]
I understand most of it but these two parts. I can't seem to understand. Could someone please help me on this?
[[image]
[image]

This is how far I've got, but I don't understand why the first and last two equations are correct.[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find the impedance as seen across nodes A1 and A2?

Comment: @RussellH yes :)

Comment: Your first assumptions seem incorrect. Unless you have specific constraints, you need to convince yourself that \$Z=R_{ref}//(R_{fg}+R_{esL}+Z_{C})\$ and work from there.